# RQDecomp3x3 is missing from OpenCV.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, opencv

I downloaded an OpenCV.js from [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.5/opencv.js). But I just realised that there is no RQDecomp3x3 method. I need to get angles from the rotation matrix. Any suggestion?

Comment: try this: https://forum.opencv.org/t/js-version-cannot-find-the-undistortpoints-function/8688

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Chirstoph Rachwitz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2602877/christoph-rackwitz)'s suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72514896/rqdecomp3x3-is-missing-from-opencv-js/72525574#comment128101237_72514896)

I just added `RQDecomp3x3` in `opencv_js.config.py`, and compiled the library again

```
calib3d = {
'': [
    ...
    'projectPoints',
    'undistort',
    'RQDecomp3x3',
    ...
],
```

}